# GC pressure on Gen2: is that a normal behaviour?

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, vscode-debugger

I have a pretty big 32bit (mandatory, as some assemblies are only available at 32bit) .NET app, running on a i7 machine with 16GB of RAM available that takes data from a camera (OCR & image) via LAN, writes on a local DB and sets some output for the PLC interpretation.
After a while (hours) that the program runs, it start to freeze, not letting the process proceeding smoothly as it should.

At first glance I thought I was facing a memory leak due to some bad practice implemented in the code (lot of IDisposable obj where not disposed at all...)

After fixing all of those, compiled the app with the `/LARGEADDRESSAWARE` flag, the app started working better overall, but still after some hours it faces a crash.

As due to the HW requirements, I'm not able to reproduce the problem, I connected the Visual Studio Remote Debugger in Production, and, starting from the logging in of the app, to the end of the process, I found an *incredibly high(?)* pressure of the GC on the Gen2.

[image: GC in yellow]

(I beleive high as for some other similar apps, the frequency is way far less, but I could be wrongly interpretating...)

By looking at the info the VS RemoteDebugger gives, those GC-Fires happen forcibly on Gen2.

[image]

The app overall runs always from 150MB to 210MB max before it freezes and crashes.

By searching similar questions, I saw more that someone suggesting to set the `<gcServer enabled="true"/>` and
I gave it a try, but it still show the same pressure as the above picture. (Can't talk about real performances as I'm waiting to be able to profile it while the SW is at full use)

Is there a way to let the app *eat* more resources before firing the GC on the 2ndGen?

Could the causes be still related to a poorly designed code?

NB: I can't share any lines of code about that sw, sorry for that.

EDIT:
Giving a look at what is in the Gen2Heap, I found loads of String objs, that probably come from an Internal method called by the Cameras (Cognex) that sends data over the net, unfortunately I'm not sure how I can handle this situation as the namespace of objs I retrieve from the debugger is not listed in the SDK Documentation.

The image below shows a snapshot of the heap taken from the VS RemoteDebugger (without giving information on which Gen)

[image]

Comment: _"Could the causes be still related to a poorly designed code?"_ - yes, it is highly likely. Though taking in account the task it seems that you will need to do GC quite a lot. But first of all the limit of 200 MB looks a bit strange to me - if you have 16 GBs at the server I wounder why it uses only that much. You need to find out what limits the process memory consumption.

Comment: Other than that without ability to profile the app it is very hard to tell. Check what is allocated and what is in the Gen2. Maybe this will give you a hint or maybe you will be able to change the allocation patterns (also check that process is actually using only 200 MBs).

Comment: I would consider looking not only at the GC but at Windows resources overall. When you say you had a problem with Disposables and you are dealing with hardware you are dealing mostly with things not covered by the GC. You might run out of things like ui handles, GDI resources etc. That should be investigated also and those resource problems will surface as OutOfMemory in dotnet.

Comment: Maybe your app allocates and deallocates too often? Did you consider re-using memory that is allocated only once and never deallocated? And what about the DB connection? Is it being opened and closed a lot? Like for every data frame you receive? Same goes for the network connection over which you receive the data.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride the DataBaseManager is a Singleton instance wich is recalled in every method that perform a read/write by opening an MySqlDataReader rdr and calling rdr.Close() before ending the method.

Comment: @Ralf Fortunately GDI obj seems to be correctly collected, it appears from the task manager that there's usually 230/250 GDI obj alives. The 'funny' this is that every time it crash, or just freeze till we got it down, it never ever gave an OutOfMemory.

Comment: Looks like it might be an unmanaged heap leak. Try using ANTS Memory Profiler, which can analyze this.

Comment: "16GB of RAM" doesn't matter. Your 32 bit app will only get 4 GB virtual memory on a 64 Bit machine and 2 GB on a 32 Bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future readers, that behaviour was caused by an explicit periodic call to `GC.Collect()` inside an external dll.
The debugger is showing those calls as 'Forced'.